# In extjs how to get selected radio buttons actual value?

Tags: extjs, radio-button

I am working in extjs. i am displaying 10 questions and its related options. On the click of submit button,i want to retreive selected radio buttons value. I am having view form as=
QbqnsView.js

```
  Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsView',
           {
        extend:'Ext.view.View',
        id:'qbqnsViewId',
        alias:'widget.QbqnsView',
        //store:'kp.PollStore',
        store:'qb.QbqnsStore',
        config:
        {
            tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
                '<div id="main">'+
                '</br>'+
            //  '<b>Question :-</b> {pollQuestion}</br>'+
                '<b>Question :-</b> {question}</br>'+

                '<tpl for="options">'+     // interrogate the kids property within the data
                //'<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{optionId}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
                 '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{parent.questionId}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
                //'<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="{questionId}">&nbsp{option}</p>'+
                '</tpl></p>'+
                '<p>---------------------------------------------------------</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</tpl>',
            itemSelector:'div.main',    
        }
```

Qbqns.js=

```
 Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.Qbqns',   
        {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires:[
              'Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsView'
              ],
              id:'qbqnsId',
              alias:'widget.Qbqns',
              title:'Qbqns',
              //height:400,
              items:[
                     {
                         xtype:'QbqnsView',
                                             },
                     ],//end of items square
                     buttons:[
                              {
                                  xtype:'button',
                                  fieldLabel:'Vote',
                                  name:'vote',
                                  formBind:true,
                                  text:'submit',
                                  // action:'voteAction',
                                  listeners: { 
                                      click: function(btn,e,eOpts) {
                                     var answers =               

    Ext.core.DomQuery.select("input[type='radio']:checked");
   console.log(answers);                                         


            }
                                  }

                              }
                              ]
```

So on the click of submit button,its giving me value as 'input,input,......'  . Its not giving me actual option value. So how to retrive actial value of selected option? Please help me

Comment: Why don't you use the radio button component of ExtJS?

Comment: Thanx sir for reply. but i am generating questions and its options dynamically by accepting questions and its options through json file. So how to use radio button component to dynamically create question and its options? can you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code to get selected radio button -

```
//put value of {parent.questionId} in getElementsByName()
var inputs = document.getElementsByName(""); 
var radio = "";  
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].checked) {
    radio  = inputs[i].name;
  }
}
```